# line 56 syntax error: unexpected end of file

Tags: bash, syntax

I have typed out the code for this `mychoice.sh` bash example and I keep getting the syntax error: unexpected end of file.

Am I missing something?

mychoice.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

E='echo -e';e='echo -en';trap ";exit" 2
ESC=$( $e "\e")
TPUT(){ $e "\e[${1};${2}H";}
CLEAR(){ $e "\ec";}
CIVIS(){ $e "\e[25l"}
DRAW(){ $e "\e%\e(0";}
WRITE(){ $e "\e(B";}
MARK(){ $e "\e[7m";}
UNMARK(){ $e "\e[27m";}
R(){ CLEAR ;stty sane;$e "\ec\e[37;44m[J";};
HEAD(){ DRAW
    for each in $(seq 1 13);do
    $E "   x                    x"
    done
    WRITE;MARK;TPUT; 1 5
    $E "BASH SELECTION MENU         ";UNMARK;}
    i=0; CLEAR; CIVIS;NULL=/dev/null
FOOT(){ MARK;TPUT 13 5
    printf "ENTER - SELECT,NEXT         ";UNMARK;}
ARROW(){ read -s -n3 key 2>/dev/null >&2
     if [[$key = $ESC[A ]];then echo up;fi
     if [[$key = $ESC[B ]];then echo dn;fi;}
M0(){ TPUT  4 20; $e "Login info";}
M1(){ TPUT  5 20; $e "Network";}
M2(){ TPUT  6 20; $e "Disk";}
M3(){ TPUT  7 20; $e "Routing";}
M4(){ TPUT  8 20; $e "Time";}
M5(){ TPUT  9 20; $e "About  ";}
M6(){ TPUT 10 20; $e "Exit   ";}
LM=6
MENU(){ for each in $(seq 0 $LM);do M${each};done;}
POS(){ if [[ $cur == up ]];then ((i--));fi
    if [[ $cur == dn ]];then ((i++));fi
    if [[ $i -lt 0 ]];then i=$LM;fi
    if [[ $i -gt $LM ]];then i=0;fi;}
REFRESH(){ after=$((i+1)); before=$((i-!))
    if [[ $before -lt 0 ]];then before=$LM;fi
    if [[ $after -gt 0 ]];then after=0;fi
    if [[ $j -lt $i ]];then UNMARK;M$before;else UNMARK;M$after;fi
    if [[ $after -eq 0 ]] || [$before -eq $LM ];then 
        UNMARK; M$before; M$after;fi;j=$i;UNMARK;M$before;M$after;}
INIT(){ R;HEAD;FOOT;MENU;}
SC(){ REFRESH;MARK;$S;$b;cur='ARROW';}
ES(){ MARK;$e "ENTER = main menu ";$b;read;INIT;};INIT
while [[ "$0" != " " ]]; do case $i in
    0) S=M2;SC;if [[ $cur == "" ]];then R;$e "\nS(w     )\n";ES;fi;;
    1) S=M2;SC;if [[ $cur == "" ]];then R;$e "\nS(ifconfig  )\n";ES;fi;;
    2) S=M2;SC;if [[ $cur == "" ]];then R;$e "\nS(df -h )\n";ES;fi;;
    3) S=M2;SC;if [[ $cur == "" ]];then R;$e "\nS(route -n  )\n";ES;fi;;
    4) S=M2;SC;if [[ $cur == "" ]];then R;$e "\nS(date  )\n";ES;fi;;
    5) S=M2;SC;if [[ $cur == "" ]];then R;$e "\nS($e by oTo )\n";ES;fi;;
    6) S=M2;SC;if [[ $cur == "" ]];then R;exit 0;fi;; 
esac;POS;done;
```

Comment: Can I suggest you use www.shellcheck.net and then post here if you need help interpreting the results?

Answer (score 3):

You can run your script through [shell checker](https://www.shellcheck.net/):

```
$ shellcheck myscript

Line 7:
CIVIS(){ $e "\e[25l"}
^-- SC1009: The mentioned parser error was in this function.
       ^-- SC1073: Couldn't parse this brace group.
                    ^-- SC1083: This } is literal. Check expression (missing ;/\n?) or quote it.

Line 23:
         if [[$key = $ESC[A ]];then echo up;fi
            ^-- SC1035: You need a space after the [[ and before the ]].

Line 24:
         if [[$key = $ESC[B ]];then echo dn;fi;}
            ^-- SC1035: You need a space after the [[ and before the ]].

Line 42:
        if [[ $after -eq 0 ]] || [$before -eq $LM ];then 
                                 ^-- SC1035: You need a space after the [ and before the ].

Line 56:

^-- SC1056: Expected a '}'. If you have one, try a ; or \n in front of it.
^-- SC1072: Missing '}'. Fix any mentioned problems and try again.

$
```

As the shell checker tells us you need to change line 7 from:

```
CIVIS(){ $e "\e[25l"}
```

to:

```
CIVIS(){ $e "\e[25l";}
```

Answer (score 1):

Couple of comments:

- Don't use variables for calling commands as in `E='echo -e';e='echo -en'`; use functions instead with at least somewhat descriptive names.  Alternatively use `printf` if you need backslash interpretation
- add spaces after `test` command, `[` and `[[` (and yes, it's not an operator, it's [actually a command called "test"](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009696899/utilities/test.html) and `[` is just a shorthand for it, that's why you need spaces)
- use lowercase letters for function and variable names ( this will avoid confusion with standard environment variables )
- in addition to what WinEunuuchs2Unix already posted, shellcheck also notes one more thing:

  ```
  SC(){ REFRESH;MARK;$S;$b;cur='ARROW';}
                        ^-- SC2154: b is referenced but not assigned.
  ```

  This variable `$b` is not assigned, so consider either getting rid of it if it's not going to be used or assign some value to it.

Comment: The code I typed out was from the Linux Manual Vol 48 by BDM Publications. I do wonder how they got $b to work?